# Apply back action to uiButton

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I need to have a UIButton (with a class of RtnBtn) which basically replicates the back button action used in the navigation bar action at the end of a process - I'm fairly new to IOS dev and I'm not sure how to approach this -  should it be done via a push or is there a better option to apply coded action directly to the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post some code here, what you have done?, you can add custom back button by below code,

```
UIButton *buttonBack = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[buttonBack setBackgroundImage:YOURImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[buttonBack addTarget:self action:@selector(backPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:buttonBack] autorelease];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

Method to handle event,

```
 -(void)backPressed
 {
   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the button, specify a selector as it's action, and in that method call `popViewController:animated:` on your navigation controller.

Answer (score 1):

If I did not understand wrong, you need this;

```
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```