# UIBarButtomItem get action selector

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

I need to change UIBarButton position at runtime, programmatically.

If I use

```
UIBarButtonItem *b = photoEditor.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem;
CGRect frame = b.customView.frame;
frame.origin.x = frame.origin.x + 20;
```

position not change

Then I want recreate button using...

```
UIBarButtonItem * btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                         initWithTitle:title
                         style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                         target:target
                         action:selector];
```

but I can't access to action information.

To get target, b.target, but if I want b.action?

Answer (score 0):

Try solution of this link [Apply back action to uiButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564150/apply-back-action-to-uibutton/19564223#19564223), in it set frame for button as per your need.

After that when you want to change frame again use below code

```
    UIBarButtonItem *item = self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem;
    UIView *view = [item valueForKey:@"view"];
    [view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 56, 31)]; // Frame as per your need.
     self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = item;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to get action selector, Apple documentation if the right place to get an answer: [UIBarButtonItem reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIBarButtonItem/action) :

```
@property(nonatomic) SEL action
```

Answer (score 0):

you can

```
 UIBarButtonItem *item = self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem;
```

item setWidth:56;